# Typescript - generate TS object from array

Tags: arrays, object, typescript

My problem is that i get an information from server - array of objects. And i would like to "push" every object from array to new object so the inupt looks:

```
[{key : value}],[{key2:value2}]....
```

**And the output should look like:**

```
{key:value,
 key2: value2 ... }
```

I don't know the syntax of "push" to make new object look like my desire output.

Comment: why are you pushing array objects into a single object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fun little trick:

```js
const input = [{key: 'value'}, {key2: 'value2'}];
// Object.assign() always returns any with rest arguments, 
// you should cast to the actual type you're expecting here. 
const result = Object.assign({}, ...input) as MyApiType;

console.log(result);
```

### How does this work?

`Object.assign()` will take an arbitrary number of arguments, and merges them.

```
Object.assign({}, {hello: 'world'}, {goodbye: 'world'}); 
// {hello: 'world', goodbye: 'world'}
```

We pass an empty object as the first parameter and **spread** `input` into the rest of the parameters.

### Why the `{}, ...input`? Why not just `...input`?

Because `Object.assign()` is destructive, it mutates the first argument passed to it. If I were to call `Object.assign(...input)`, `input[0]` would have been changed. We want to avoid changing the input, because it's usually unexpected behavior to those looking at the code from the outside.

Comment: In ES6 you can just do `Object.assign({}, ...input)`.

Comment: You are correct. I started with `[{}].concat(input)` and moved to `[{}, ...input]`, but that one is better

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is not **push** put **Array.reduce** (plain old js). It allows you to reduce the array to a single object. You can use it this way.

```js
let data: [{ key: string, value: string }] = [{
    key: '1',
    value: '2'
}];

let obj = data.reduce((prev, current) => {
    prev[current.key] = current.value;
    return prev;
}, {});
```